# How does the servlet know that the browser has disabled cookies?

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, sessiontracking

I would be grateful if someone would explain how servlets can tell that cookies have been disabled on the client's browser.

I understand that while creating a session in a servlet:
If cookies are enabled, the server will return the sessionID as a cookie.
If cookies are disabled, the sessionID will be written into the URL.

What I don't understand is how the server can tell that cookies have been disabled.
HTTP is a stateless protocol, there is no way (that I know of) the server can tell that the client has disabled cookies.
I expect that the server would not receive cookies in the request header but that could mean that no cookies have been set in the first place.

I have checked these answers:
[Servlet HttpSession cookies disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33396871/servlet-httpsession-cookies-disabled)
[Manage Session when broswer has disable cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795998/manage-session-when-broswer-has-disable-cookies)

They both explain how to enable URL-rewriting but they do not explain how the server knows cookies have been disabled on the client.

Answer (score 1):

> how servlets can tell that cookies have been disabled

They can't. 
When the session is first created, the server sends the session ID both as a cookie and with URL rewriting. On the second request, if it receives the session cookie, then it stops rewriting URLs.